# How to remove mail client from Elementary OS Loki 0.4

Tags: software-installation, pantheon-mail

How I can remove the mail client from Elementary OS Loki 0.4 through command line? I don't need it but can't uninstall it in the Application Center as it freezes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AppCenter is still in development so it can be buggy. In Terminal, use:

```
sudo apt purge pantheon-mail
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use included App Center, in updates tab, find "Mail", choose "Uninstall" and enter password. After that mail will be removed from Your PC